# Обрезать начало файла

Tags: delphi, файлы

Нужно отсечь у файла некоторое количество байт в начале, файл очень большой.
В делфи есть функция Truncate, которая обрезает концовку файла. Нету ли чего-то подобного для обрезания определенного количества байт в начале файла?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Нет. Чтобы отрезать конец файла надо просто в файловой системе прописать новую длину. А вот чтобы отрезать начало файла, надо двигать всё содержимое, поэтому быстро это не получится и никакой готовой функции для этого не предусмотрено.
2. Теоретически существуют случаи, в которых начало можно отрезать или дописать быстро - если размер изменяется на число, кратное размеру кластера файловой системы. Но программ, делающих такое, не нашлось, по крайней мере, для ntfs. Впрочем, для линуксовых файловых систем тоже ничего такого не гуглилось.

Comment: Обычно в таких случаях просто создают новый файл и копируют в него содержимое старого с нужного места. После чего просто удаляют старый.